# Evaluation of series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to prove or disprove $\displaystyle \left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k-b_k}{3^k} \right| \leqq \left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k-b_k}{2^k} \right| $ where $a_k=0,1$ and $b_k=0,1$

Intuitively, this is correct because $\dfrac{1}{3^k}\leqq \dfrac{1}{2^k} $.

But I can't prove
$\displaystyle \left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k-b_k}{3^k} \right| \leqq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\frac{a_k-b_k}{3^k}\right|
\leqq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left|\frac{a_k-b_k}{2^k}\right|$ .

I can't proceed from here.

I would like you to give me some ideas.

Comment: Hint: Show that you can assume $a_1-b_1=1-0=1$, and that that makes both series non-negative without the need for absolute value signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counter example,
Let $a_k=0$, $b_k=1$ for $k=1$ and $a_k=1$,$b_k=0$ for $k \ne 1$
We then have

$$\left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k-b_k}{3^k} \right|=\left|\frac{-1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{81}+\cdots\right|=\left|\frac{-1}{6}\right|=\frac{1}{6}$$
$$\left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k-b_k}{2^k} \right|=\left|\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}+\cdots\right|=0$$
$$\left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k-b_k}{3^k} \right| > \left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k-b_k}{2^k} \right|$$
Thus disproving the statement.

Comment: Why do you use `\displaystyle` and `\dfrac` in MathJax when you're actually in display mode rather than inline?